# "chunkedEncodingError, Connection broken: OSError 104" when transferring ~20 tables from BigQuery into MongoDB (via Python)

Tags: python, mongodb, google-bigquery, connection, airflow

To preface the question, I am not sure if this is an issue with:

(a) Airflow and the GCP compute engine that it is deployed / running on,

(b) Python's connection to BigQuery (using the [BigQuery API client library for python](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries))

(c) Python's connection to MongoDB (using pymongo / MongoClient)

... and so tagging the question accurately was difficult. To summarize quickly, we have an Airflow `DAG` with 20 tasks, where each task queries data from a single BigQuery table into a pandas dataframe, then cleans up the data quickly, and then inserts the data into a MongoDB collection. Each task is running this same function for a different `table_name` from BigQuery:

```
def transfer_all_by_partitioned_key(table_name, partition_key):
    
    start_time = time.time()
    print(partition_key)

    # (1) Connect to BigQuery + Mongo DB
    bq = bigquery.Client()
    cluster = MongoClient(MONGO_URI)
    db = cluster["mydb"]
    print(f'====== (1) Connected to BQ + Mongo: {round(time.time() - start_time, 5)}')
    
    # (2) Create list of options, in order to transfer data in chunks
    get_partitions_query = f"select distinct {partition_key} from myprojectid.mydataset.{table_name}"
    partitions_df = bq.query(get_partitions_query).to_dataframe()
    
    # (3) Loop DF, query + write to Mongo for each partition
    db[table_name].drop() # drop table, as we are recreating it entirely here
    for index, row in partitions_df.iterrows():
        
        # Run Query
        iter_value = row[partition_key]

        iter_query = f"select * from `myprojectid.mydataset.{table_name}` where {partition_key} = {iter_value}"
        iter_df = bq.query(iter_query).to_dataframe()
        print(f'====== {index}: ({iter_value}) {iter_df.shape[0]} rows updated on this date')


        # Handle Dates
        row1_types = iter_df.iloc[0].apply(type) # missing data in 1st row may be issue
        date_cols = [key for key in dict(row1_types) if row1_types[key] == datetime.date]
        for col in date_cols:
            iter_df[[col]] = iter_df[[col]].astype(str) # .where(iter_df[[col]].notnull(), None)

        # Handle DateTimes
        datetime_cols = [key for key in dict(iter_df.dtypes) if is_datetime(iter_df[key])]
        for col in datetime_cols:
            iter_df[[col]] = iter_df[[col]].astype(object) # .where(iter_df[[col]].notnull(), None)
        
        # Insert into MongoDB
        db[table_name].insert_many(iter_df.to_dict('records'))
```

Because of the chunking / looping (to avoid memory issues in Airflow), each task can query from BigQuery + write to MongoDB up to 500 times. As for the issue - seemingly randomly, I receive the following error from time to time for these tasks:

```
requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError: ('Connection broken: OSError("(104, \'ECONNRESET\')")', OSError("(104, 'ECONNRESET')"))
```

This has happened at different times for 3 of the 20 tasks, and it seems like this error is prone to happen for any task at any time... however, when the task is cleared and rerun in Airflow, it generally works the second time (not so reproducible).

Maybe I am querying from BigQuery, or inserting into MongoDB, too frequently?

Here is the full error from the Airflow logs:

```
[2020-07-29 22:39:20,735] {{taskinstance.py:1145}} ERROR - ('Connection broken: OSError("(104, \'ECONNRESET\')")', OSError("(104, 'ECONNRESET')"))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 313, in recv_into
    return self.connection.recv_into(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1840, in recv_into
    self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1663, in _raise_ssl_error
    raise SysCallError(errno, errorcode.get(errno))
OpenSSL.SSL.SysCallError: (104, 'ECONNRESET')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 437, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 764, in read_chunked
    self._update_chunk_length()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 694, in _update_chunk_length
    line = self._fp.fp.readline()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 318, in recv_into
    raise SocketError(str(e))
OSError: (104, 'ECONNRESET')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 751, in generate
    for chunk in self.raw.stream(chunk_size, decode_content=True):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 572, in stream
    for line in self.read_chunked(amt, decode_content=decode_content):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 793, in read_chunked
    self._original_response.close()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 455, in _error_catcher
    raise ProtocolError("Connection broken: %r" % e, e)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection broken: OSError("(104, \'ECONNRESET\')")', OSError("(104, 'ECONNRESET')"))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 983, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 113, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 118, in execute_callable
    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/plugins/tasks/geniussports/transfers.py", line 223, in transfer_all_by_partitioned_key
    iter_df = bq.query(iter_query).to_dataframe()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job.py", line 3374, in to_dataframe
    create_bqstorage_client=create_bqstorage_client,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/table.py", line 1741, in to_dataframe
    for frame in self.to_dataframe_iterable(dtypes=dtypes):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/table.py", line 1435, in _to_page_iterable
    for item in tabledata_list_download():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/_pandas_helpers.py", line 563, in download_dataframe_tabledata_list
    for page in pages:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/page_iterator.py", line 249, in _page_iter
    page = self._next_page()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/page_iterator.py", line 369, in _next_page
    response = self._get_next_page_response()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/table.py", line 1367, in _get_next_page_response
    method=self._HTTP_METHOD, path=self.path, query_params=params
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 556, in _call_api
    return call()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 286, in retry_wrapped_func
    on_error=on_error,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 184, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 419, in api_request
    timeout=timeout,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 277, in _make_request
    method, url, headers, data, target_object, timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 315, in _do_request
    url=url, method=method, headers=headers, data=data, timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/auth/transport/requests.py", line 450, in request
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 683, in send
    r.content
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 829, in content
    self._content = b''.join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or b''
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 754, in generate
    raise ChunkedEncodingError(e)
requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError: ('Connection broken: OSError("(104, \'ECONNRESET\')")', OSError("(104, 'ECONNRESET')"))
```

Comment: Did you find out something?